# Read variable further down in code in shell script

Tags: sh

In a shell script I need to know the value of a variable further down in the code, without running through it first.

This pings `$IP` which is extracted from `$VAR` below the `while` loop.

The `$VAR` is unknown at the time this is extracted `(IP=$(echo $VAR | awk '{print $1}'))`

Is it possible to read `VAR` in before the while loop runs?

The code:

```
#!/bin/sh

TIMEOUT=10
IP=$(echo $VAR | awk '{print $1}')

while [ $TIMEOUT -ne 0 ];do

    ping -c 1 -W 1 "$IP" >/dev/null

    rc=$?

    if [ $rc -eq 0 ];then

        TIMEOUT=0

    else

        TIMEOUT=$(($TIMEOUT - 1))
        echo $TIMEOUT
        sleep 1

    fi

done

# rest of code to run after while loop
VAR="192.168.0.1 t,r 20,e"
```

Comment: Why aren't you simply defining `VAR` earlier. To answer your primary question, no, you cannot set the value of `IP` without already knowing the value of `VAR`.

Comment: I could, I was just wondering if that is possible, and google failed me in finding an answer to this.

Comment: Expanding further, is it not possible to read ahead somehow?

Comment: Just ask yourself what is the value in `$VAR` at the time you call `IP=$(echo $VAR | awk '{print $1}')`. Scripts do things line-by-line. Why not `VAR="${1:-192.168.0.1 t,r 20,e}"` *up top* to be able to pass the value of `VAR` as the first argument to your script or use the default.

Comment: OK, I get it. Thanks all, I'll set $VAR ahead of the while loop.